# Feeding the 'shape key' value from a variable in python script

Tags: scripting, shape-keys

For the sake of mathematical accuracy i need the shape key to change as i change a variable declared in python. I know how to declare a variable in python. Now how do i use that value to determine my shape key values. [image: matrix transformation]
This actually can be a general question:- how do I use a value of a variable declared in python terminal at any other place in the GUI editor. Eg- declare a vector of numbers in python and set the z position of an object to change accordingly at every frame. I have a feeling that it is easily possible through scripting(though i have not tried it) but is there any graphical way of setting this condition?

Comment: [Drivers and shape-keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers+shape-keys)

Comment: could you please explain some more, I could not follow or understand what that post meant.